# How to add php from database into individual html divs

Tags: php, html, css

I am creating a search, and what I want is when the user searches they will be able to see a number of different attractions appear. At the minute when I search the data appears in a long list.

```
 else {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
    $attraction_name = $row['attraction_name'];
    $lat = $row['lat'];
    $long = $row['long'];
    $cost = $row['cost'];
    $image = "<img src='{$row['image']}' height='100' width='100'>";

    $output .= '<div>'.$attraction_name.' '.$lat.' '.$long.' '.$cost.' '.$image.'</div>';

    }
}
```

I have added a simple html format which looks like the following

```
<div class="col-md-4">
<div class="thumbnail">
     <?php print ("$output");?>
</div>
```

However the html appears all the time and I don't want this. What I would like is to create a search and then when the search results are returned they will appear in the html divs. Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: mixing quote-types (ie: `'` & `"`) is asking for trouble. I'd change to single-quotes on your `$image` variable and use `.` concatenation instead to keep things consistent.

Comment: @admcfajn I have edited this slightly, however the whole searched list is being adding to the one div. Is there anyway I could separate each attraction into seperate html divs?

Comment: stop posting the same question over and over and over again.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I am not posting the same question over and over, this is the first time I have asked this question??

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap HTML in PHP logic like so:

```
<?php
if ($hasResults)
{ ?>
    <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <?php print ("$output");?>
    </div>
<?php }
?>
```

Comment: Where do I define the $hasResults?

Comment: I just used that as a stand-in for any boolean value.  However you are determining whether or not you have results.

Comment: I added $result in replace because that is a variable that I defined earlier, but it still says undefined variable